# Qt N9 Changing scroll direction when showing a page

Tags: qt, qml

Language: Qt Quick (QML)

Platform: Qt Creator 2.4.1

Target device N9

Hi

Normally when a new Page is showed, for example with

```
      onClicked: {
          pageStack.push(Qt.resolvedUrl("ExitDialog.qml"))
      }
```

the new page is "sliding in from the right", is it possible to change this behaviour ?

I want to change the the sliding so the new window comes in from the left and 
is "leaving" to the left when closing.

Is there a tag to Page/PageStackWindow which change this ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add needful system qml-files to your project and edit it.
For your example, change code from PageStack.qml:

```
// Start state for pop entry, end state for push exit.
State {
   name: "left"
   PropertyChanges { target: container; x: -width }
},
// Start state for push entry, end state for pop exit.
State {
   name: "right"
   PropertyChanges { target: container; x: width }
},
```

to

```
// Start state for pop entry, end state for push exit.
State {
   name: "left"
   PropertyChanges { target: container; x: width }
},
// Start state for push entry, end state for pop exit.
State {
   name: "right"
   PropertyChanges { target: container; x: -width }
},
```

And I also want to know how to do it easier.

Comment: Ahh, nice, did not think of copy and editing system file, however this will alter the behaviour for all Page's, is there a way to do it for single Pages ?

Comment: Everything is possible =) Use some PageStack's roles to set different behaviors (animations) of pages.